# Eclipse : Insufficient Memory in Device. Even though it has

Tags: android, space

I have been developing an app that I tested it on a real device after adding making minor improvements each time. Even though the app was around 2~3 Mb finally in size. It showed Insufficient Memory event though I had 20 MB Free Space to install an app.

**Edit:** Don't know why but when I asked the question, I had not much knowledge of static variables so I thought they take much space. But this statement was framed in-appropiately without a meaning

Comment: java 101. too vague, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a vast topic  but to be concise,

yes static can take space after the app stoped, but if the system does need this memory space, those static references will be released.

You should be aware of that because on resuming your app,  you shouldn't expect those static variables to be already set ( they can be release without any notification ) so anyway you have to reset them. So the better is to set them to null yourself so you don't get surprised if they are automatically released.

they shouldn't take so much memory space because large objects ( like bitmaps or other big ressources ) shouldn't be kept statically its something to avoid.

also keep in mind that biggest memory leak in android are often due to static references on Context objects ( this is also something to avoid!). in the same way, any view have got a reference on its context so don't keep anystatic reference on views either.

they would be so much to say ...   I hope those advises suit what you wanted to know.